# IONIC 3 - IOS Keyboard Overlap <ion-footer> while switching to emoji keyboard

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, sass, ionic3

Greeting! As per title state, it seems like IONIC 3 Keyboard is not working fine on IOS. The keyboard is overlapping  if switching to Emoji keyboard.

Like previous version of IONIC 1, there have directive 'keyboard-attach'. But starting IONIC 2, the directive is gone already and this keyboard issue came.

Anyone have solution for this? Below is my HTML code:

```
<ion-footer style="background-color: #f1f1f1; padding-bottom: 0px;">
   <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-row class="message_row">
         <ion-col col-10>
            <ion-item no-lines>
               <input type="text" placeholder="Don't be shy, say something..." class="chatInput">
            </ion-item>
         </ion-col>
         <ion-col col-2>
            <button color="primary" (click)="sendMessage()" ion-button icon-only clear>
               <ion-icon color="tom" name="md-send"></ion-icon>
            </button>
         </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
   </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

SCSS code as below:

```
.chatInput {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    border:0px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

And here is the screen shot:

[image: IONIC 3 IOS Keyboard Issue]

Thanks